# In angular, create spa without # in links and with no server modifications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hyperlink, single-page-application

I am creating an Angular 1 SPA and I added

```
<base href="/">
```

and

`$locationProvider.html5Mode({enable:true, requireBase:false});`

So , now my links are like `http://localhost:1234/about` , without the `#` character.

My problem is that if I paste that URL in a browser, I will get an empty response, because this is the default behiavior. It tries to grab the "about" html page that does not exist.

When I visit a URL I dont want to get an empty response. How can I fix this , without server modofications? If this is not possible, what server modifications I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you use nginx as your web server, you should configure it like this:

```
server {
    listen 1234;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /path/to/angular/project;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```